# The minimum range of a $n \times n$ grid

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n > 1$ be a integer, we put $1, 2, \cdots n^2$ into the cells of a $n \times n$ grid.
Let the **range** of the grid be the maximal difference between two cells that are **in the same row or in the same column**. Find the minimum range of all possible grids.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ even let $n=2k$.

$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&\cdots & k^2-k + 1&k^2+1&\cdots&2k^2-k+1\\
\vdots  & \ & \vdots& \vdots&\ &\vdots\\
k &\cdots & k^2 & k^2+k& \cdots \ & 2k^2\\
n^2-2k^2+1&\cdots&n^2-k^2-k+1&n^2-k^2+1&\cdots&n^2-k+1\\
\vdots&\ &\vdots&\vdots&\ &\vdots\\
n^2-2k^2+k&\cdots&n^2-k^2&n^2-k^2+k&n^2-k&n^2\\
\end{array} \right)$

is an optimal solution. ($\cdots$) stands for "increasing by $k$" and ($\ \vdots\ $) for "increasing by $1$".

All rows and columns are increasing. We therefore find the range by considering the differences of the last and first entry in each row and column. The maximum for this is $n^2-2k^2+k-1$, or in terms of $n$: $$\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac n 2 -1.$$

Proof that this is optimal: We are trying to place the smallest and the largest numbers in a way in which they interfere (i.e. are in the same row or column) with the least difference. This is done by putting the smallest $k^2$ numbers in the top left corner and the largest $k^2$ in the bottom right. The next number we have to place is $k^2+1$ (or equivalently $n^2-k^2$). You will see that this yields that the minimum difference in the row or column in which we place it is $n^2-2k^2+k-1$. By filling up the other fields, we obtain an optimal matrix.

For odd $n$ the lowest $\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^2$ numbers can be put in the top left corner and the highest $\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2$ in the bottom right. This would give a minimum range of $$n^2-\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{n-1}{2}=\frac 1 2 (n^2+n-2),$$
as this is the minimal difference between the lest element which does not fit into the bottom right corner any more and the elements in the top left corner it interferes with.

Comment: Why should we put the smallest $k^2$ numbers in the top left corner and the largest $k^2$ in the bottom right. The difference between $k^2$ and $n^2 - k^2 + 1$ is lower than $n^2 - 2k^2 + k - 1$. Maybe these two numbers can be put into one row.

Comment: You just want to make sure that the smallest and the largest numbers don't interfere too early. There are several ways to do that, but that's a very simple one. In fact, switching rows or columns of the matrix will never change the range.
If you put $n^2-k^2+1$ and $k^2$ into one row, there will also be other numbers in the row already, because we have filled up the top left and bottom right corners. You need to consider the difference between all the elements in the row and the column.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts on small cases:
$$n=1: (1) \text{ has range } 0 \text{ (trivial)} \\
n=2: \pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} \text{ has range } 2 \text{ (trivial)} \\
n=3: \pmatrix{1&2&5\\3&6&8\\4&7&9} \text{ has range } 5 \text{ (seems optimal)}$$
The general Idea:
WLOG Put a $1$ in the $A_{11}$ entry and $n^2$ in any entry not in $A_{1\cdot}$ not in $A_{\cdot1}$. Proceed alternating smallest / biggest placement and try to minimze the "partial range" i.e. the range disregarding empty entries.